# multiple Azure VM deployment in selective zone

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-vm-templates

I'm trying to deploy two VMs in to selective availability zones in my Azure subscription. I was referring the code below to to get an idea how zone works with Azure VM deployment.

`"zones": "[split(string(add(mod(copyIndex(),3),1)), ',')]"`

Now I am trying to parameterize or introduce variable in some way so that I can have two different zone explicitly defined for two VMs and but works with any zone number between 1 to 3.

Does anyone know how I would achieve this?

Comment: Having difficulty understanding your second paragraph. It sounds like you want to introduce parameters, that allow you to deploy two VMs to two different zones explicitly, BUT that work in any zone number between 1 and 3. What is the purpose of the part after "but", if you are otherwise using parameters to explicitly deploy to specific zones? I sort of think I see what you're saying, but can't really be sure.

Comment: Put another way, how do you decide which zone a vm should belong to?